# How to add a New User to AD?

Tags: web-part

I have a list for personel.

I want add new user to AD when adding a new item in personel list.

I use this code but don't created user

```
private SPUser CreateUser(string strLoginName, string strEMail, 
string strName, string strNotes, string strSiteURL)
{
SPUser spReturn = null;
SPSite spSite = null;
SPWeb spWeb = null;

try
{
    //Open the SharePoint site
    spSite     = new SPSite(strSiteURL);
    spWeb     = spSite.OpenWeb();

    //Assign role and add user to site
    SPRoleAssignment spRoleAssignment = 
        new SPRoleAssignment(strLoginName, strEMail, strName, strNotes);
    //Using Contribute, might need high access
    SPRoleDefinition spSPRoleDefinition = 
        spWeb.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"]; 

    spRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(spSPRoleDefinition);
    spWeb.RoleAssignments.Add(spRoleAssignment);

    //Update site
    spWeb.Update();
    spReturn = spWeb.AllUsers[strLoginName];
}
catch(Exception)
{ 
}
finally
{
    spWeb.Close();
    spSite.Close();
}

return spReturn;
}
```

**EDIT**

The following worked for me:

```
 SPUser user = spWeb.EnsureUser(strLoginName);
 SPRoleAssignment spRoleAssignment = 
 new SPRoleAssignment(user);
```

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. Are you saying you want to add an item to SharePoint list and have that create a user in AD? Or are you referring to user profile synchronization?

Comment: Or maybe hes looking for a webpart to manage AD? http://adselfservice.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes , I want created a webpart for manage AD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need [Event Receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg252010.aspx) to handle ItemAdded event, something like this:

```
class YOUR_EVENTHANDLER_CLASS_NAME : SPItemEventReceiver
    {

        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {

           //Your Code to Add User To AD
        }

     }
```

you can read current item with this line:

```
SPListItem personelItem = properties.ListItem;
```

then you need to read personelItem fields (for username and other info you need to add to AD) and then you must write [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298449/create-active-directory-user-in-net-c?__=973540860) to Add User To Active Directory

Comment: Thanks, I need Event Receiver to handle ItemAdded event and then i want add user to AD . but i don't use this code in sharepoint.

Answer (score -2):

it seems to sync the items in the sharepoint list as new users to the AD. It is possible.

Comment: I can  add a new user to manually?